# What is the name for UIControlState to get the value when subclassing UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am subclassing UIButton.
But I need to know the **state** that the button is in to draw the color of button for up or down:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
     if (state==UIControlStateNormal) {
         //draw rect RED
     }
     if (state==UIControlEventTouchDown) 
         //draw rect BLUE
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you even try looking at the docs?

1. Goto [UIButton Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)
2. Check the properties
3. Nothing obvious
4. See if `UIButton` has a superclass
5. Goto [UIControl Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) - `UIButton`'s superclass
6. Check the properties
7. Oh look there is a `state` property

---

## Update

The accepted answer is slightly incorrect and could lead to some annoyingly difficult bug to track down.

The header for `UIControl` declares `state` as

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIControlState state;                  // could be more than one state (e.g. disabled|selected). synthesized from other flags.
```

Now looking up to see how `UIControlState` is defined we see

```
enum {
    UIControlStateNormal       = 0,                       
    UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
    UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
    UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
    UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
    UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
};
typedef NSUInteger UIControlState;
```

Therefore as you are dealing with a bit mask you should check for the state appropriately e.g.

```
if (self.state & UIControlStateNormal) { ... }
```

---

## Update 2

You could do this by drawing into an image and then setting the image as the background e.g.

```
- (void)clicked:(UIButton *)button;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(button.frame.size);

    // Draw gradient

    UIImage *gradient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Ok I am able to get the state by (Tracking Touches and Redrawing Controls)... but I am not sure how about properly doing this... begin continue end

Comment: It would most likely be easier to just provide some images for the different states...

Comment: I have to draw various shades and and stuff depending on previous selections... math computations

Comment: You could draw them to an image and set the resulting image as the buttons background.

Comment: Is it more or does "if (self.state & UIControlStateNormal) { ... } " not actually hold up. UIControlStateNormal is 0, so AND'ing it with anything will always be false in that if statement

Comment: @GauntFace Yup that's right :/ personally in this case I wouldn't fight the API and would just use `setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>`...

Answer (score 1):

Since `state` is a property, you can use `self.state` to access it.

Update:

See the next answer's update.

Comment: I made the assumption that the drawRect is called when the button state changes... I was wrong...  do you know what function call drawRect to redraw it?  thx

Comment: Overwrite -setState and call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` inside it. But the `UIButton` is not a plain `UIView`, it contains `UILabel` or `UIImageView`, may be you should consider others ways than `drawRect:`.

Answer (score 0):

To redraw rect, I did this...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    myState = 1;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    myState = 0;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    NSLog(@"drawRect state: %d", self.state);
    NSLog(@"rect %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (myState==0){
    ///////// plot border /////////////
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 1, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 1, 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 299, 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 299, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillPath(c);
    CGContextClosePath(c);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
    }else{
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 1, 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 1, 40);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 299, 40);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 299, 20);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillPath(c);
    CGContextClosePath(c);
    CGContextStrokePath(c); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are just changing the background for selected and normal states why not set background images? Or is your actual implementation using dynamic colours?

Comment: this is just a starting point for drawing graphics on the buttons